# Update (skip) wait duration on AWS Step Function

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-step-functions

I have a Step Function set up that has a 'wait' state (eg, 999999 seconds). Once the wait is over, the Step Function invokes a Lambda. Sometimes, I will want to interrupt the wait time and trigger the Lambda immediately. Is this possible?

I thought I could do it by using the `aws-sdk` with the Step Functions API to manually skip the wait; but I've been experimenting with no success.

I tried the API's Start Execution method, but it is only for starting the entire Step Function (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html) I can't find anything for manipulating individual steps.

I can use [GetExecutionHistory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetExecutionHistory.html) to return an event object that describes the Wait step, eg:

```js
{
    timestamp: 2022-10-17T08:38:27.849Z,
    type: 'WaitStateEntered',
    id: 2,
    previousEventId: 0,
    stateEnteredEventDetails: {
      name: 'Wait',
      input: '{\n    "Comment": "Insert your JSON here"\n}',
      inputDetails: {truncated: false}
    }
  },
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way to manipulate this event to move to the next step.

Comment: You can divide and conquer. Split your step-functions into two separate ones, and trigger the second both from the `WAIT` state and the external event.

Comment: Thanks @Guy. That was an alternative I was also considering. I feel like having multiple Step Functions is a bit contrary to their intent, but I can't really think of any major drawbacks, other than proliferation of code/SF's and more complicated audit trails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spoken to AWS tech support who have confirmed that there is nothing in the `aws-sdk` or the `aws-cdk` that provides for the update of an existing state (eg, a 'wait' state) while it is running. There are some workarounds:

1. AWS tech support suggest [Iterating a loop using a Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html). This basically loops over a Choice>Wait>Lambda>(repeat) where the Lambda returns an output that tells the Choice whether to continue with the loop or else direct the Execution to another state. The advantage of this is that we don't need to cancel the Execution and we maintain a simpler record of activities. The disadvantage is that we are regularly invoking a Lambda.
2. As per @Guy's suggestion, we could split the Step Function into two separate Step Functions. This means we could cancel the initial Step Function and then trigger the latter Step Function manually.

We can cancel the execution of a Step Function with [stopExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StopExecution.html). For example, using the `aws-sdk`:

```js
import { config, Credentials, StepFunctions } from "aws-sdk"; // package.json:   "aws-sdk": "^2.1232.0",

config.update({ region: "eu-west-2" });
const stepFunctions = new StepFunctions();

const stoppedExecution = await stepFunctions
 .stopExecution({
   executionArn: "...",
   cause: "...",
   error: "...",
  })
 .promise();
```

We can then trigger a new Step Function with [startExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html)

3. Step Functions also allow us to [Wait for a callback with the Task Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token). Basically, the Execution step state will send a task token (eg, to a Lambda), then wait to be returned the Task Token. Once received the Execution will proceed to the next step.

There are two ways I can think of proceeding from above item 3.:

a. [Configure a Heartbeat Timeout for a Waiting Task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#wait-token-hearbeat). If the Heartbeat Timeout ends without a response token being received, the task fails with a States.Timeout error name. We can (I assume) handle the error in the Task rule to trigger the next step anyway. So the default behaviour is now to trigger the next step after a duration elapses, and then we also have the facility to skip the wait duration by sending the Task Token back to the Execution.

b. Use another Service to perform the wait function and return the Task Token after the wait duration has elapsed.

Comment: You can also check the callback pattern (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/callback-task-sample-sqs.html). You can send the token back from a scheduled CW event or when you got the trigger to stop waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 of your answer would still require some service/process to handle/poll whether or not to continue I believe.

Ive implemented a pattern very similar to your description but can be defined in a single sfn defintion.

> note: I consider this a hack/abuse of the States Language but it has the benefit of keeping a single state machine definition/execution and prevents paying for excessive state transitions in the looping method:

1. put your `Wait` state in a new `Parallel` state.
2. add a *waitforcallback* type task in the `Parallel` state. (dynamodb, sqs, etc) making sure to configure timeout/heartbeat to the same duration  as the "neighboring" `Wait` state.
3. If/when you want to "short circuit" the wait duration, query wherever you stored the task token, and send a `SendTaskFailure`
   with a unique cause/error payload.
4. configure the `Catch` (FallBack state) for  the `Parallel` state to point to your "Invoke Lambda" state
5. Also configure the default(?) `Next` field for the `Parallel` block to point to your "Invoke Lambda" state

This may not be very intuitive but it relies on the fact that if any state defined in a parallel state fails, that entire block will fail immediately. with some custom error handling though, you can "ignore" the "special sentinel error", thus short circuiting the long wait duration and proceed to your next state.

its def not perfect and youll have to play around with errors/timeouts/heartbeats that make sense for your usecase.

depending on how many executions/transitions you expect, the easiest thing ive found is just making sure the task token ends up in a predictable cloudwatch log group, then query with cloudwatch logs insights when i need to retrieve it again